# Using an AWS ACM certificate private key on an EC2-hosted HTTPs server

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

We'd like to use ACM to manage our certificates, allowing us to easily create them on the fly for a third-party (using CNAME validation).  This works great, except we can't appear to get the private key we'd need to support the certificate via our frontend server, which is hosted by AWS but otherwise managed independently of any other AWS service.  (It's essentially an Express server running on an EC2 instance.)

Is it possible to get the key value(s) out of ACM so that we can bootstrap a Node https server using them?  Or does Amazon not support this at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The private key for an ACM certificate is maintained entirely within the service. There is no support for exporting the private key.

ACM certificates can only be used on specific AWS services. For more information see [ACM FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/faqs/) and [Supported services](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/faqs/#services_used).